# connecting to salesforce using SAS

Tags: odbc, salesforce, sas

I have a client with salesforce enterprise edition.  I need to connect to and extract the salesforce data using Base SAS (SAS/Access for ODBC is licensed).

How can this be achieved?  Is it possible to map a libname using an ODBC engine, or is it necessary to use the web APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about Salesforce support for ODBC, but certainly it is possible to map a libname using ODBC.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/91pdf/sasdoc_91/access_odbc_7365.pdf
has examples - basically it is

```
libname <name> odbc <connection options>;
```

Salesforce specific SAS product:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/bidsag/61236/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003279102.htm

That requires more than base SAS, of course, but if SAS BI is an option it seems pretty easy to configure.

Another option that is not free (well, it seems to be free for 15 days):
http://blogs.datadirect.com/2012/02/sas-access-to-salesforce-crm-for-superior-odbc-integration-with-sas.html

It doesn't seem like there is a free ODBC driver for Salesforce, though, unless something's changed - example, http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bqqu seems to suggest it's something desired but not available.

So for free solution you may want to use the Web API...

Comment: Never got this to work in the end - but I think the datadirect ODBC driver would have been the best option.